# Retrieving posts by their date and category

Tags: posts, categories, wpdb, date

I'm trying to create a plugin for displaying post titles and dates (which will be displayed as links to those posts) of a specific date range and category. So far I have managed to get to display the posts in between the dates, but I can't wrap my head around the WP category thing. I have no idea how to connect those two into a single SQL query.
Here's the code so far:

```
function izvjestaj($attr) {
    global $wpdb;
    $start .= $attr['godina'] . "-09-01";
    $end .= $attr['godina'] + 1 . "-08-31";
    $cat = $attr['cat'];

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT * 
        FROM wp_posts, wp_terms 
        WHERE post_date 
        BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' 
        ORDER BY post_date");

    foreach($posts as $post): 
        echo "<a href='./?p=" . $post->ID . "'>" . $post->post_date . " " . $post->post_title . "</a><br />";
    endforeach;
}
add_shortcode('izvjestaj', 'izvjestaj');
```

So basically I want to create a plugin that can be used with the shortcode:

```
[izvjestaj godina=2010 cat=some_category]
```

and that it displays the titles and dates of those posts. Basically a report of posts.

*(translations cro>eng : 'godina' = 'year', 'izvjestaj' = 'report')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following  code:

Following code has to be added in shortcode function

```
 global $wpdb;
    $start .= $attr['godina'] . "-09-01";
    $end .= $attr['godina'] + 1 . "-08-31";
    $cat = $attr['cat']; //$cat must be category name.
    $cat_term_id=get_term_by('name', $cat, 'category');
    $term_id=$cat_term_id->term_id;
    $query = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', 
      'tax_query' => array(array( 'taxonomy' => 'category',
                               'field' => 'term_id',
                               'terms'=>$term_id
                               )),

      'post_status' => 'publish',

      'date_query'     => array(
                                array(
                                    'after'     => $start,
                                     'before'    => $end,
                                     'inclusive' => true,
                               )
                        )
    );

$query_str = new WP_Query( $query );
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code. Also don't post multi answers. Rather edit the original answer

Comment: I've tried it, I get no errors this time but I also don't get any posts back and I've tried with several years and categories.

Comment: My upper comment is my own fault. I tried the code in a hurry between lectures and totally forgot to actually DISPLAY the results. It works perfectly now, thank you very much!